# Problema para especificar y generar un Main procedure en GeneXus

Tags: c#, genexus

Estoy usando Ev2 U3.

Estoy teniendo problemas para hacer un build de un main procedure

A fin de cuentas, el error aparece como:

> ========== DummyGenerarSello Compilation started ========== gxexec "C:\Models\SNAP_Ev2_EBG\CSharpModel\web\bldadummygenerarsello.cs"
>   -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" No se pudo encontrar el archivo
>   'C:\Models\SNAP_Ev2_EBG\CSharpModel\web\bldadummygenerarsello.cs'.
>   DummyGenerarSello Compilation Failed
>   ========== Web config update started ========== Updating web config ... Web config update Success Build With This Only Failed

La parte que me llama la atención es la de no poder encontrar el archivo BLDxxxxx.cs

Qué necesito hacer para que GeneXus genere este archivo?

Saludos y gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar si no hay algún error antes de especificación o generación. 
Y qué propiedades no default tiene ese procedimiento, si es main y command line.
Hice pruebas de crear un procedimiento main y luego hacer Build With this Only y no puedo reproducir ese error.
Ese archivo BLDxxx.cs debería generarse siempre que se genera el adummygenerarsello.cs del procedimiento main.